# Place Font-awesome caret up and caret down stacked adjacent

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I need a output like below

[image]

My HTML code is like below

```
<div>
    <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
</div>
<div>
    <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

My CSS code is like below

```
   .fa, .fas {
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
        font-weight: 900;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 30px;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
```

I am gettting output like below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this once..

```css
.arrow i {
 font-size: 50px;
 margin: 2px 0;
 padding: 0 3px;
 line-height: 20px;
}
.arrow {
 line-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="arrow up"><i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="arrow down"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sunil Rajput. Your solution is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this css:

```
.fa-caret-down{
position:relative;
}

.fa-caret-down:before {
    content: "\f0d7";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.fa, .fas {
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: it is not working. I am getting output like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/IerPu.png

Answer (score 1):

```css
.ab{
 
 border: 1px solid;
 width:30px;
 height:40px;
 margin-left:30px;
 
 
}
.ac{
 
 border: 1px solid;
 width:30px;
 height:40px;
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-top:10px;
  
 
}
```

```html
<div class="ab"><i class="fa fa-caret-up" style="font-size:48px;"></i></div>
<div class="ac"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="font-size:48px;"></i></div>
```